# token based authentication in polymer

Tags: polymer-1.0, jwt

I Have a simple question.I Have started using Polymer for my app having sails js as backend.For authentication purpose i used JWT(json web tokens) in sails js and before this i worked on Angularjs as front end with [Satellizer](https://github.com/sahat/satellizer) handling token based authentication.

Now I want to use token based authentication in [This Dashboard](http://polymer-dashboard.com/)  which by default is using sessions as authentication. I couldn't find any source around to use token based approach for [polymer 1.0](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/)

I want help  here????

Comment: Take a look at https://auth0.com/blog/build-your-first-app-with-polymer-and-web-components/